# How to use circle-translate to move a geojson circle 50% of its dynamic radius

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox layer where I've got multiple GEOJson features with the exact same co-ordinates (so they stack on top of eachother).

To prevent the issue of them being stacked, I wish to use the `circle-translate` option to move each circle away from the other one. If each circle was `20px` wide, this would be easy as I could move one `10px` to the left and the other `10px` to the right.

My issue is that the radius of each circle is generated based on the value of the feature, so some of are bigger than others. Therefore I need the `translate` value to be 50% of the circle's diameter.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code for my layer

```
const LNG = {
  name: 'LNG',
  id: 'lng-markers',
  showDetailsOnHover: true,
  source: {
    type: 'geojson',
    data,
  },
  type: 'circle',
  paint: {
    'circle-color': '#E74133',
    'circle-translate': [-10, -10],
    'circle-radius': [
      'interpolate',
      ['exponential', 1],
      ['number', ['get', 'LNG']],
      0,
      7,
      10,
      10,
      100,
      15,
      1000,
      20,
      10000,
      25,
      100000,
      30,
      1000000,
      35,
      10000000,
      40,
      100000000,
      45,
    ],
  },
  opacity: 70,
  checked: true,
  offset: { bottom: [0, -10] },
  childLayers: [
    {
      id: 'lng-markers__props',
      type: 'symbol',
      filter: ['>', `${ 'LNG' }`, 0],
      source: 'lng-markers',
      layout: {
        'text-field': `{${ 'LNG' }_en}`,
        'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
        'text-size': 12,
      },
      paint: {
        'text-color': '#FFFFFF',
        'text-translate': [-10, -10],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be really straightforward if `circle-translate` supported data-driven styling. You would simply use the same expression, but with values half the size.

Alas, it doesn't.

You may have to look at modifying your GeoJSON data before it gets added to the map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, supporting data-driven styling is currently an open issue but probably won't be implemented for a while